# jQuery triggered CSS Animation not working

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am using the following CSS animation to show and hide an element on my website:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateUp {
 0% {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
   -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
 }
 100% {
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
   -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px);
 }
}

@keyframes rotateUp {
 0% {
   opacity: 1;
   transform-origin: 0 0;
   transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
 }
 100% {
   opacity: 0;
   transform-origin: 50% 0;
   transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px);
 }
}

.rotateUpOut {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
 backface-visibility: visible !important;
 -webkit-animation: rotateUp 1s ease 0s forwards;
 animation: rotateUp 1s ease 0s forwards;
}

.rotateUpIn {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
 backface-visibility: visible !important;
 -webkit-animation: rotateUp 1s ease 0s forwards;
 animation: rotateUp 1s ease 0s forwards;
 -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
 animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

I use jQuery to fire the animations via a `click` function, which works fine.

The issue I have is that the `rotateUpOut` animation does not fire after the `rotateUpIn` animation - it simply hides the div immediately, whereas other animations work fine. This one, for example, works perfectly:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(300px);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(300px);
  }
}

.rotateDownOut {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -webkit-animation: rotateDown 1s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: rotateDown 1s ease 0s forwards;
}
```

What's happening here?

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znxgma9h/

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle if possible?

Comment: I wish you were provide a fiddle, try to use https://api.jquery.com/finish/ at least.

Comment: -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
 animation-direction: reverse;

did you try this on .rotateUpOut and delete them from .rotateUpIn?

Comment: Edited to include fiddle.

Comment: give 1s delay on animation rotateDownOut  animation: rotateDown 1s ease 1s forwards;